# Hibernate null parameter native query Spring Boot

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to pass a null parameter (:searchQuery) to a native query in Spring Boot, I have tried various different ways but whenever I pass null I get the error

> ERROR: operator does not exist: text ~~ bytea

Query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT count(*) FROM analysis_history ah, analysis_group ag WHERE ah.analysis_group_id = ag.id "
+ "AND ah.creation_date BETWEEN :from AND :to AND ((:searchQuery IS NULL) OR (:searchQuery IS NOT NULL AND ag.name LIKE :searchQuery))", nativeQuery = true)
Long count(@Param("from") Date from, @Param("to") Date to, @Param("searchQuery") String searchQuery);
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `like null`

```
SELECT count(*) FROM analysis_history ah, analysis_group ag 
WHERE ah.analysis_group_id = ag.id AND ah.creation_date 
BETWEEN :from AND :to AND ag.name LIKE :searchQuery
```

And you pass '%' in the searchQuery when the searchQuery parameter is null? e.g.

```
repository.count(from, to, searchQuery == null ? "%" : searchQuery);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this have a performance impact though? I basically want to ignore the searchQuery if it's null

Comment: Yes it has. In that case I would create two different queries

Comment: Problem is, I have a multiple of different combinations so would be duplicating everything.  Hibernate must support optional/null parameters?

Comment: That's not Hibernate. You have a SQL statement. So you should first try to make this SQL statement run outside of your application.

Comment: It does run as a native query in my db client with the nulls.  Thanks anyway, I'll try some alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to bypass this, but you need access to the EntityManager, and not use the `@Query` annotation to create that implementation for you.

```
Long count(Date from,Date to, String searchQuery) {
    Number n = em.createNativeQuery("... that query")
            .setParameter("from", from, TemporalType.DATE) // assuming that's a Date, and not TimeStamp
            .setParameter("to", to, TemporalType.DATE)
            .setParameter("searchQuery", "")
            .setParameter("searchQuery", searchQuery)
            .getSingleResult();
    return n.longValue();
}
```

The first call to `.setParameter("searchQuery", "")` tells Hibernate what type this is, the next one sets the value.

The problem comes from Postgres doing the typecheck during parsing, and not deferring the error in case the parameter set is a null.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative workaround to the issue posed by @coladict, which is compatible with Query and performs as well as the original would.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM analysis_history ah, analysis_group ag 
WHERE ah.analysis_group_id = ag.id 
AND ah.creation_date BETWEEN :from AND :to 
AND (:searchQuery IS NULL OR ag.name LIKE CAST(:searchQuery AS CHARACTER VARYING))
```